# Database Transaction Notifying of Changes When no Changes Made when using Database Link

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper, toad

I use sqldeveloper (but this problem has also been duplicated on TOAD, so I don't think it's specifically related to sqldeveloper).  The basic problem is after I run a complex `SELECT` query that uses a database link through sqldeleloper, it will notify that I have changes that need to be rolled back or committed when I go to close my session.  The weird part is that I was only running a `SELECT` query and there are no changes to `COMMIT`.  Can someone explain this behavior to me?

Comment: an implicit transaction occurs when selecting over a dblink.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An implicit transaction occurs when selecting over a dblink.

> When Oracle performs a distributed SQL statement Oracle reserves an
>   entry in the rollback segment area for the two-phase commit
>   processing. This entry is held until the SQL statement is committed
>   even if the SQL statement is a query

More on this [here](http://www.jlcomp.demon.co.uk/faq/dblink_commit.html).  I'll try to dig up an Oracle link if I can.

More from the horses mouth:)

> Two-Phase Commit Mechanism
>
> A database must guarantee that all statements in a transaction,
>   distributed or non-distributed, either commit or roll back as a unit.
>   The effects of an ongoing transaction should be invisible to all other
>   transactions at all nodes; this transparency should be true for
>   transactions that include **any type of operation, including queries**,
>   updates, or remote procedure calls.

More from Oracle's [Distributed Database Concepts](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/ds_concepts.htm#i1008726) guide